# How do you change characters like number expression &#39; in json file into special characters like small quotation marks?

Tags: reactjs, json

How do you change characters like number expression `&#39;` in json file into special characters like `small quotation marks` when network communication is done with Mock Data?

```
"snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-05-21T03:46:13Z",
        "channelId": "UC3IZKseVpdzPSBaWxBxundA",
        "title": "BTS (방탄소년단) &#39;Butter&#39; Official MV",
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uImkN.png)

```
export default function Home() {
  const {
    isLoading,
    error,
    data: bts,
  } = useQuery(["bts"], async () => {
    return fetch("data/bts.json").then((res) => res.json());
  });

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>{error}</p>;

  return (
    <div className={styles.video}>
      {bts.items.map((video) => (
        <VideoCard
          key={video.id.videoId}
          id={video.id.videoId}
          thumbnails={video.snippet.thumbnails.medium}
          title={video.snippet.title}
          channel={video.snippet.channelTitle}
          publish={video.snippet.publishTime}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I brought the data in this way

Does calling with actual url reflect normal special characters?

Comment: How is this text generated? The standard way to escape quotes or double quotes in JSON is to use `\\`, not HTML entities, eg \' or \". Whatever service produces the non-standard JSON should be fixed

Comment: Check [the standard ways of escaping](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-8) in RFC7159. No JSON parser will be able to handle HTML entities, at least not without custom coding. The source should be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render html entities.

```js
const App = () => {
    const title = 'BTS (방탄소년단) &#39;Butter&#39; Official MV'
  
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: title}} />
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

You can also create a function which will give you decoded html string.

```js
const decodeHtml = (html) => {
    let txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}

console.log(decodeHtml("BTS (방탄소년단) &#39;Butter&#39; Official MV"));
```